# SortedDictionary add one SortedDictionary into another

Tags: c#, .net, sorteddictionary

I have a requirement where I already have an existing `SortedDictionary<string, int>`. Now I am creating a different `SortedDictionary` and like to add this in the first one . How to do it?

Comment: Is the second also a SortedDictionary<string, int> or is it a SortedDictionary<something, SortedDictionary<string, int>>?

Answer (score 4):

Just pass it to the constructor:

```
var copy = new SortedDictionary<string, int>(original);
```

Answer (score 1):

`SortedDictionary<TKey,TValue>` doesn't provide an `AddRange(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)` function, so you'll have to do it the hard way, one item at a time.

```
SortedDictionary<string, int> first, second;
first = FillFirst();
second = FillSecond();

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in second) {
  first.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```